# Where does Event.Keys gone?

Tags: events, keyboard, mootools

Did I miss something or the Event.Keys object has gone from mootools since 1.4.0 ?

I cannot get the real value of a key or compare it to the current pressed key :

```js
var modifiers = {
    previous: Event.Keys.left,
    next: Event.Keys.right
};
```

```js
switch (evt.code){
    case Event.Keys.backspace:
        // Do some stuff;
        break;
    case Event.Keys.delete:
        // Do some other stuff
        break;
}
```

Is ther a possibility this object has move to another object or property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

erm. Under the new API changes, `Event` is now known as `DOMEvent`, a MooTools `Type`, not a Class. Additionally, event definitions are now private behind a closure in a keys array.

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Types/DOMEvent.js

There is an API to work with it:

```
DOMEvent.defineKeys({
    38: "up"
});
```

which, regretfully - is one way: You have no getter for the `Event.Keys`, you cannot set it w/o going through the API either.

You can redefine them as per the source or store a local var of what they mean. You can also refactor it to puncture it.

You can also do pseudo events, like `keydown:left`

```
DOMEvent.definePseudo('left', function(split, fn, args){
    // args[0] is the Event instance
    if(args[0].key == 'left') fn.apply(this, args);
});


document.getElement("textarea").addEvent("keydown:left", function(e) {
    alert("left pressed!");
});
```

the alert above will only fire if you press the left arrow inside your textarea. Hope this helps...

Comment: Ok, thank you for this explanation, I will go through thoses cool pseudo events.